# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.criterion.Criterion

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, maven

I've deployed my web application [CourseWebApplication.war] using Wildfly 9.0.2 under Eclipse.

In the folder: `...\wildfly-9.0.2.Final\standalone\deployments\CourseWebProject.war\WEB-INF\lib` there is a jar [CourseProject.jar] which includes Dao of the various tables mapped in the db and several servlets (mapped in CourseWebProject's web.xml).
Both of jar and war are builded with Maven and have hibernate dependencies in their pom.xml: hibernate-core, hibernate-commons-annotations and hibernate-jpa-2.0-api.

`Exception handling request to /CourseWebProject/home: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/criterion/Criterion` is thrown everytime I run my `HomeServlet` servlet. I checked (in debug) that the above exception is thrown when it tries to istance a new DaoImpl object but I don't understand why:

CourseProject/HomeServlet.java

```
   public class HomeServlet extends HttpServlet 
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
    {
        doPost(request,response);
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        String username = request.getParameter("userName");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");
        if(username!=null && !username.isEmpty() && password!=null && !password.isEmpty())
        {
            Users user = new Users();
            user.setUsername(username);
            user.setPassword(password);
            **DaoInterface dao = new DaoImpl();**
```

Log server

```
2017-06-12 10:45:15,358 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.4.3.Final
2017-06-12 10:45:15,629 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.2.6.Final
2017-06-12 10:45:15,705 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYSRV0049: WildFly Full 9.0.2.Final (WildFly Core 1.0.2.Final) starting
2017-06-12 10:45:15,707 DEBUG [org.jboss.as.config] (MSC service thread 1-6) Configured system properties:
    awt.toolkit = sun.awt.windows.WToolkit
    file.encoding = Cp1252
    file.encoding.pkg = sun.io
    file.separator = \
    java.awt.graphicsenv = sun.awt.Win32GraphicsEnvironment
    java.awt.headless = true
    java.awt.printerjob = sun.awt.windows.WPrinterJob
    java.class.path = C:\Users\Riccardo\Downloads\wildfly-9.0.2.Final\jboss-modules.jar
    java.class.version = 52.0
    java.endorsed.dirs = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\endorsed
    java.ext.dirs = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext;C:\windows\Sun\Java\lib\ext
    java.home = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre
    java.io.tmpdir = C:\Users\Riccardo\AppData\Local\Temp\
    java.library.path = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin;C:\windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;native;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_131/bin/../jre/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_131/bin/../jre/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_131/bin/../jre/lib/amd64;C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.4\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Lenovo\FusionEngine;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Lenovo\Bluetooth Software\;C:\Program Files\Lenovo\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\lenovo\easyplussdk\bin;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Users\Riccardo\Downloads\eclipse;;.
    java.net.preferIPv4Stack = true
    java.runtime.name = Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
    java.runtime.version = 1.8.0_131-b11
    java.specification.name = Java Platform API Specification
    java.specification.vendor = Oracle Corporation
    java.specification.version = 1.8
    java.util.logging.manager = org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager
    java.vendor = Oracle Corporation
    java.vendor.url = http://java.oracle.com/
    java.vendor.url.bug = http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/
    java.version = 1.8.0_131
    java.vm.info = mixed mode
    java.vm.name = Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
    java.vm.specification.name = Java Virtual Machine Specification
    java.vm.specification.vendor = Oracle Corporation
    java.vm.specification.version = 1.8
    java.vm.vendor = Oracle Corporation
    java.vm.version = 25.131-b11
    javax.management.builder.initial = org.jboss.as.jmx.PluggableMBeanServerBuilder
    javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory = __redirected.__DatatypeFactory
    javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory = __redirected.__DocumentBuilderFactory
    javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory = __redirected.__SAXParserFactory
    javax.xml.stream.XMLEventFactory = __redirected.__XMLEventFactory
    javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory = __redirected.__XMLInputFactory
    javax.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactory = __redirected.__XMLOutputFactory
    javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory = __redirected.__TransformerFactory
    javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory:http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema = __redirected.__SchemaFactory
    javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory:http://java.sun.com/jaxp/xpath/dom = __redirected.__XPathFactory
    jboss.bind.address = localhost
    jboss.bind.address.management = localhost
    jboss.home.dir = C:\Users\Riccardo\Downloads\wildfly-9.0.2.Final
    jboss.host.name = arm-pc
    jboss.modules.dir = C:\Users\Riccardo\Downloads\wildfly-9.0.2.Final\modules
    jboss.modules.system.pkgs = org.jboss.byteman
    jboss.node.name = arm-pc
    jboss.qualified.host.name = arm-pc
    jboss.server.base.dir = C:\Users\Riccardo\Downloads\wildfly-9.0.2.Final\standalone
    jboss.server.config.dir = C:\Users\Riccardo\Downloads\wildfly-9.0.2.Final\standalone\configuration
    jboss.server.data.dir = C:\Users\Riccardo\Downloads\wildfly-9.0.2.Final\standalone\data
    jboss.server.deploy.dir = C:\Users\Riccardo\Downloads\wildfly-9.0.2.Final\standalone\data\content
    jboss.server.log.dir = C:\Users\Riccardo\Downloads\wildfly-9.0.2.Final\standalone\log
    jboss.server.name = arm-pc
    jboss.server.persist.config = true
    jboss.server.temp.dir = C:\Users\Riccardo\Downloads\wildfly-9.0.2.Final\standalone\tmp
    line.separator = 

    logging.configuration = file:/C:/Users/Riccardo/Downloads/wildfly-9.0.2.Final/standalone/configuration/logging.properties
    module.path = C:/Users/Riccardo/Downloads/wildfly-9.0.2.Final/modules
    org.jboss.boot.log.file = C:/Users/Riccardo/Downloads/wildfly-9.0.2.Final/standalone/log/boot.log
    org.jboss.logmanager.nocolor = true
    org.jboss.resolver.warning = true
    org.xml.sax.driver = __redirected.__XMLReaderFactory
    os.arch = amd64
    os.name = Windows 8.1
    os.version = 6.3
    path.separator = ;
    program.name = JBossTools: WildFly  9.x
    sun.arch.data.model = 64
    sun.boot.class.path = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\sunrsasign.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\classes
    sun.boot.library.path = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\bin
    sun.cpu.endian = little
    sun.cpu.isalist = amd64
    sun.desktop = windows
    sun.io.unicode.encoding = UnicodeLittle
    sun.java.command = org.jboss.modules.Main -mp C:/Users/Riccardo/Downloads/wildfly-9.0.2.Final/modules -jaxpmodule javax.xml.jaxp-provider -jaxpmodule javax.xml.jaxp-provider org.jboss.as.standalone -b localhost --server-config=standalone.xml -Djboss.server.base.dir=C:\Users\Riccardo\Downloads\wildfly-9.0.2.Final\standalone
    sun.java.launcher = SUN_STANDARD
    sun.jnu.encoding = Cp1252
    sun.management.compiler = HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers
    sun.os.patch.level = 
    sun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval = 3600000
    sun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval = 3600000
    user.country = US
    user.country.format = IT
    user.dir = C:\Users\Riccardo\Downloads\wildfly-9.0.2.Final\bin
    user.home = C:\Users\Riccardo
    user.language = en
    user.language.format = it
    user.name = Riccardo
    user.script = 
    user.timezone = Europe/Berlin
    user.variant = 
2017-06-12 10:45:15,710 DEBUG [org.jboss.as.config] (MSC service thread 1-6) VM Arguments: -Dprogram.name=JBossTools: WildFly  9.x -Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dorg.jboss.boot.log.file=C:/Users/Riccardo/Downloads/wildfly-9.0.2.Final/standalone/log/boot.log -Dlogging.configuration=file:/C:/Users/Riccardo/Downloads/wildfly-9.0.2.Final/standalone/configuration/logging.properties -Djboss.home.dir=C:/Users/Riccardo/Downloads/wildfly-9.0.2.Final -Dorg.jboss.logmanager.nocolor=true -Djboss.bind.address.management=localhost -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252 
2017-06-12 10:45:17,535 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 21) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'job-repository-type' in the resource at address '/subsystem=batch' is deprecated, and may be removed in future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.
2017-06-12 10:45:17,540 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 10) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'enabled' in the resource at address '/subsystem=datasources/data-source=ExampleDS' is deprecated, and may be removed in future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.
2017-06-12 10:45:17,634 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYDS0004: Found CourseWebProject.war in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called CourseWebProject.war.dodeploy
2017-06-12 10:45:17,635 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYDS0004: Found HelloWeb.war in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called HelloWeb.war.dodeploy
2017-06-12 10:45:17,677 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0039: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
2017-06-12 10:45:17,706 INFO  [org.xnio] (MSC service thread 1-6) XNIO version 3.3.1.Final
2017-06-12 10:45:17,720 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] (MSC service thread 1-6) XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.3.1.Final
2017-06-12 10:45:17,796 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.io] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 37) WFLYIO001: Worker 'default' has auto-configured to 8 core threads with 64 task threads based on your 4 available processors
2017-06-12 10:45:17,850 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jsf] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 44) WFLYJSF0007: Activated the following JSF Implementations: [main]
2017-06-12 10:45:17,891 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 46) WFLYNAM0001: Activating Naming Subsystem
2017-06-12 10:45:17,914 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYNAM0003: Starting Naming Service
2017-06-12 10:45:17,923 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 33) WFLYJCA0004: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)
2017-06-12 10:45:17,936 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 38) WFLYCLINF0001: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
2017-06-12 10:45:17,949 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) WFLYSEC0002: Activating Security Subsystem
2017-06-12 10:45:17,954 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 56) WFLYWS0002: Activating WebServices Extension
2017-06-12 10:45:17,962 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYSEC0001: Current PicketBox version=4.9.2.Final
2017-06-12 10:45:17,963 WARN  [org.jboss.as.txn] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) WFLYTX0013: Node identifier property is set to the default value. Please make sure it is unique.
2017-06-12 10:45:17,975 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYJCA0009: Starting JCA Subsystem (IronJacamar 1.2.5.Final)
2017-06-12 10:45:17,993 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = h2
2017-06-12 10:45:18,188 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYMAIL0001: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
2017-06-12 10:45:18,278 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 55) WFLYUT0003: Undertow 1.2.9.Final starting
2017-06-12 10:45:18,289 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYUT0003: Undertow 1.2.9.Final starting
2017-06-12 10:45:18,573 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 55) WFLYUT0014: Creating file handler for path C:\Users\Riccardo\Downloads\wildfly-9.0.2.Final/welcome-content
2017-06-12 10:45:19,589 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "CourseWebProject.war" (runtime-name: "CourseWebProject.war")
2017-06-12 10:45:19,594 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYDS0013: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory C:\Users\Riccardo\Downloads\wildfly-9.0.2.Final\standalone\deployments
2017-06-12 10:45:19,595 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "HelloWeb.war" (runtime-name: "HelloWeb.war")
2017-06-12 10:45:19,618 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBoss Remoting version 4.0.9.Final
2017-06-12 10:45:19,658 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYUT0012: Started server default-server.
2017-06-12 10:45:19,678 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYUT0018: Host default-host starting
2017-06-12 10:45:19,949 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTP listener default listening on localhost/127.0.0.1:8080
2017-06-12 10:45:20,139 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
2017-06-12 10:45:20,482 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBWS022052: Starting JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 5.0.0.Final
2017-06-12 10:45:24,837 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: /CourseWebProject
2017-06-12 10:45:24,837 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 68) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: /HelloWeb
2017-06-12 10:45:24,883 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 34) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "HelloWeb.war" (runtime-name : "HelloWeb.war")
2017-06-12 10:45:24,884 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 34) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "CourseWebProject.war" (runtime-name : "CourseWebProject.war")
2017-06-12 10:45:25,257 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
2017-06-12 10:45:25,258 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
2017-06-12 10:45:25,259 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0025: WildFly Full 9.0.2.Final (WildFly Core 1.0.2.Final) started in 10260ms - Started 352 of 539 services (232 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
2017-06-12 10:48:05,056 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-3) UT005023: Exception handling request to /CourseWebProject/home: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/criterion/Criterion
    at com.arm.course.ui.HomeServlet.doPost(HomeServlet.java:32)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:86)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:72)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:282)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:80)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:172)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:199)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:774)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.criterion.Criterion from [Module "deployment.CourseWebProject.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:205)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:455)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:404)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:385)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:130)
    ... 30 more
```

CourseWebProject/pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.arm.coursewebapp</groupId>
  <artifactId>CourseWebProject</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>CourseWebProject Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>java.net2</id>
    <name>Repository hosting the jee6 artifacts</name>
    <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>  

  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

     <dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
    <version>6.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- HIBERNATE FRAMEWORK AND DEPENDENCY -->
     <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
    <artifactId>antlr-runtime</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
    <artifactId>geronimo-jta_1.1_spec</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss</groupId>
    <artifactId>jandex</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>javassist</groupId>
    <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
    <version>3.12.1.GA</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
    <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2</version>
    </dependency>


  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>CourseWebProject</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

CourseProject/DaoImp.java

```
[public class DaoImpl implements DaoInterface
{
    private Session session = null;

    private void buildSessionFactory()
    {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.configure("/com/arm/course/model/hbm/hibernate.cfg.xml");
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();    
        session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    }

    public DaoImpl()
    {
        buildSessionFactory();
    }
```

Tree folder about  my CourseWebProject.war deployed

```
  wildfly-9.0.2.Final\standalone\deployments\CourseWebProject.war
Folder PATH listing for volume Windows8_OS
Volume serial number is BAAC-FBDE
C:.
³   Homepage.html
³   tree.txt
³   
ÃÄÄÄcss
ÃÄÄÄhtml
³       Login.html
³       loginError.html
³       loginOk.html
³       
ÃÄÄÄjs
ÃÄÄÄMETA-INF
³   ³   MANIFEST.MF
³   ³   
³   ÀÄÄÄmaven
³       ÀÄÄÄorg.arm.coursewebapp
³           ÀÄÄÄCourseWebProject
³                   pom.properties
³                   pom.xml
³                   
ÀÄÄÄWEB-INF
    ³   web.xml
    ³   
    ÀÄÄÄlib
        ÀÄÄÄCourseProject.jar
            ÃÄÄÄcom
            ³   ÀÄÄÄarm
            ³       ÀÄÄÄcourse
            ³           ÃÄÄÄdao
            ³           ³       DaoImpl.class
            ³           ³       DaoInterface.class
            ³           ³       TestDao.class
            ³           ³       
            ³           ÃÄÄÄmodel
            ³           ³   ³   Classroom.class
            ³           ³   ³   ClassroomId.class
            ³           ³   ³   Course.class
            ³           ³   ³   Location.class
            ³           ³   ³   Person.class
            ³           ³   ³   Subject.class
            ³           ³   ³   SubjectId.class
            ³           ³   ³   Users.class
            ³           ³   ³   UsersId.class
            ³           ³   ³   
            ³           ³   ÀÄÄÄhbm
            ³           ³           Classroom.hbm.xml
            ³           ³           Course.hbm.xml
            ³           ³           hibernate.cfg.xml
            ³           ³           Location.hbm.xml
            ³           ³           Person.hbm.xml
            ³           ³           Subject.hbm.xml
            ³           ³           Users.hbm.xml
            ³           ³           
            ³           ÀÄÄÄui
            ³                   HomeServlet.class
            ³                   LoginFilter.class
            ³                   LoginHomepageServlet.class
            ³                   
            ÀÄÄÄMETA-INF
                ³   MANIFEST.MF
                ³   
                ÀÄÄÄmaven
                    ÀÄÄÄcom.arm.course
                        ÀÄÄÄCourseProject
                                pom.properties
                                pom.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very into Wildfly/JBoss (I'm more into Tomcat/Spring Boot), so I'm not very sure about the expected shape of a WAR for this JEE application server.

It appears that the JBoss class loader tries to load the `Criterion` class but doesn't find it in the classpath. For a 'classic' WAR, the external libs are supposed to be in `WEB-INF/lib`, is there any Hibernate JARs in it, in addition of your `CourseProject.jar`?
It could also be in the server's lib directory, though I'm not sure it is a pretty good practice.

If this works in your IDE, check in which JAR the `Criterion` class is located, and check that this JAR is in the package you deploy. If you deploy from Eclipse, check that the binding is properly done, or just don't do that because you work on something different you will finally use: build the WAR with Maven, to be sure the final result is properly built, and then deploy it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi sjahan!

No into the 'WEB-INF/lib' I found only my 'CourseProject.jar'. 
The external Hibernate JARs I suppose that are loaded by Maven to run-time (I'm wrong???)

As soon as possible I check  in which JAR the Criterion class is located and check that this JAR is in the package I deploy..
Really thanks for the moment

Comment: Maven performs the compilation, the tests and the packaging, but it should not do anything at runtime. The `Criterion` class is supposed to be in one of hibernate JARs. If there is no hibernate JARs in your classpath, then it's absolutely normal. Anyway, the JVM rarely lies: in the end, you misses the Hibernate JARs.

Comment: For the CourseWebProject I see JARs (including those about Hibernate) under `eclipse_workspace\CourseWebProject\target\CourseWebProject\WEB-INF\lib`

but I don't see that (JARs in the project's classpath) for the CourseProject
under `eclipse_workspace\CourseProject\target`..
Is that a problem?

Comment: This is perfectly normal. A JAR is a standalone library, the dependencies are here for the compilation, but that's all. A WAR is a web application, it needs every dependencies to be able to run the application. If you have Hibernate JARs in this directory, this is good. The problem now is that your server does not seem load them, for an unknown reason. Are you sure the whole WAR is properly deployed?

Comment: I've added in the main post the tree structure about the WAR deployed into wildFly.. Fair enough for me

I understand that it is not easy to see if something is missing in the war deployed based on the text stucure I've added, but does it feel good for you?

Comment: It seems totally normal that it doesn't work: look into the WEB-INF/lib folder: I only see one JAR (CourseProject.jar) and there is no hibernate*.jar, so that is totally normal that your server tells you it does not find hibernate classes. I don't know how you generate this WAR, but the dependencies are clearly missing.